# How do you retrieve the largest element of List that matches a condition?

Tags: java, lambda

New to Java 8 and lambdas in general. Here's what I have:

A simple Credentials class:

```
public interface Credentials {

    boolean isPasswordEnabled();

    String getCreatedDate();
}
```

A simple service to return the list of credentials:

```
List<Credentials> credentials =  credentialsService.getCredentials();
```

I need to grab the most recently created password that is also enabled. This is what I have so far, but that only takes care of the date part. How do I integrate the isPasswordEnabled check?

```
Credentials latestCredentials = Collections.max(credentials, Comparator.comparing(c -> c.getCreatedDate()));
```

Comment: Be careful the date is a String, not a date or localDate it would be better to use this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a filter, then find max:

```
Credentials latestCredentials = credentials.stream()
  .filter(Credentials::isPasswordEnabled)
  .max(Comparator.comparing(Credentials::getCreatedDate))
  .get();
```

Note that since `max()` returns `Optional`, you need to then call `.get()` to get the max.

If there are no enabled elements (or `credentials` is empty), you'll get a `NoSuchElementException`. If you want to throw a particular exception for this case, instead of calling `.get()` call `.orElseThrow(SomeException::new)`.

Comment: Thanks, this is the answer I was looking for. Was getting incompatible types until the .get() was added.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
credentials.stream()
.filter(Credentials::isPasswordEnabled)
.max(Comparator.comparing(Credentials::getCreatedDate))
```

Comment: Knew it was something simple. Thanks!

Comment: It's not so trivial actually since it uses the streaming API you might not know yet, while you previously only used the collections API.